# How whatsapp find the name of the user during sign up?

Tags: android, whatsapp

I am trying to implement signup activity in android using phone number as done by whatsapp and many other applications these days. But i also need to know the name of the user but without prompting the user to enter it himself/herself. is it possible? how does whatsApp manages to do it? 
Looking for any suggestions possible here. Thanks.

Comment: Please look at these two posts: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727029/how-can-i-get-the-google-username-on-android) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727029/how-can-i-get-the-google-username-on-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ContactsContract.Profile`

```
    String name  = "";
    Cursor c = getApplication().getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Profile.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null); 
    if(c.moveToFirst()) {
     name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("display_name"));
     c.close();
   }
```

You need permissions too

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
```

Read this [Get Owner Name of an Android Device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20360506/get-owner-name-of-an-android-device)

Comment: what other information can i fetch about the owner?

Comment: Read this for more info http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Profile.html