# How to get the phone user's name?

Tags: android

My application needs the user's display name. In System Settings, under the Users section, I can see my name. That would be fine for my app. How can I get that or a similar string?

Several suggestions to how to do this I found on Stack Overflow did not work for me.

- `AccountManager` returns only the email address, which I don't need.
- `ContactsContract.Contacts` contains only other people data.
- `ContactsContract.Profile` seems to be empty.
- `ContactsContract.Data` doesn't containt that name I need.
- I wouldn't use oAuth or such login services. My app doesn't need account management, it just needs a name of the phone owner.

Comment: For Security reasons you cannot get phone user's name without accounts permission

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20360506/get-owner-name-of-an-android-device

Comment: @ShriyanshGautam The app requests `GET_ACCOUNTS`, `READ_CONTACTS` premissions, and both these + `READ_PROFILE` are listed in the manifest.

Comment: Still for gettting User's Name you need to implement Google Sign-in https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/people

Comment: @ShriyanshGautam Are you sure, there is no other option to get a short name? Getting the user's email is easy, but more dangerous...

Comment: As far as I know I am sure. You can get email ids easily but not names. You need OAuth to access Name and other Profile Informations

Comment: If you have your doubt cleared then you can accept my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get users email with GET_ACCOUTNS permission but for getting User Name you need to implement some OAuth to access User's Name and other profile informations.

One way is to user Google Sign-in developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/people

Answer (score 0):

use String getUserName () method
Returns the user name of the user making this call. This call is only available to applications on the system image; it requires the MANAGE_USERS permission.

for referenceClick [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/UserManager.html)

Comment: I can't grant that premission in an easy way. If I really need, I'll use Google Sign-in then.