# How to get the owner name and number of Android device for API 9 and higher in android?

Tags: android

I am working on an app in which i have to take the Name, Number and Email from the android device. So far I have been successful in getting the primary email address of the device by using this code.

```
        Pattern emailPattern = Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS; // API level 8+
        Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(getBaseContext()).getAccounts();
        for (Account account : accounts) {
        if (emailPattern.matcher(account.name).matches()) {
        possibleEmail = account.name;
        }
        }
```

Can i get the name and number also by doing some modification in this code?
I have to do this in API 9+

Comment: see answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9323207/how-can-i-get-the-first-name-or-full-name-of-the-user-of-the-phone

Comment: @trickedoutdavid thanks for reply..but i have already referred this question. It says you can get but for API higher than 11, but i need it for API 9+

Comment: See earlier:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6222384/possible-to-get-owner-contact-info-in-android